# Update database with arrays after checking arrays

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I am trying to update a database with array. before updating i am checking database with an array because some table has no primary key.

here is my code

```
 foreach ($compareData as $keu => $valo) { 
          $da=$processData[$keu];
          foreach ($da as $key => $value) {
       $r= DB::table($a)->where($valo)->update([$key => $value]);

         }

      }
```

after that i am getting below's error

> "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input
>   syntax for type timestamp: "" (SQL: update "kengensettei" set
>   "kengenchar01" = user where ("kengenchar01" = user and "kengenchar02"
>   =  and "kengenchar03" = qc3001 and "kengenchar04" = =見積データ新規登録=見積リスト既存データ呼出・変更=受注リスト and "kengenchar05" =  and "kengenchar06" =  and "kengenchar07" =  and "kengendate01" =  and
>   "kengendate02" =  and "kengendate03" =  and "kengenint01" =  and
>   "kengenint02" =  and "kengenint03" =  and "kengenint04" =  and
>   "kengenint05" =  and "kengenint06" =  and "kengenint07" =  and
>   "kengenint08" =  and "kengenint09" =  and "kengenint10" = )) ◀"

i have tried with different syntax but getting the same error.

By the way problem has been solved.
here is the code.

```
foreach ($compareData as $keu => $valo) { 
              foreach ($valo as $key => $val) {
                 $data[$key]=!empty($val)?$val:null;
               }

           $da=$processData[$keu];
           $r= DB::table($a)->where($data)->update($da);

          }
```

for php NUll and "" are same. but in postgresql they are totally different. so when my code is trying to check database it returns an error.

Comment: you need to paste the code of processData function because you are forming your data there so from there you might be returning some value of the some key which is not compatible with the datatype of the column where you are trying to push it

Comment: i have solved the problem.here it is*

foreach ($compareData as $keu => $valo) { 

              foreach ($valo as $key => $val) {

                 $data[$key]=!empty($val)?$val:null;

               }
  
           $da=$processData[$keu];


           $r= DB::table($a)->where($data)->update($da);

        
          }